# Transpose generate series date postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Questions about transpose are asked many times before, but I cannot find any good answer when using generate_series and dates, because the columns may vary.

```
WITH range AS
(SELECT to_char(generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-01-05', interval '1 day'),'YYYY-MM-DD'))
SELECT * FROM range;
```

The normal output from generate series is:

```
2015-12-01
2015-12-02
2015-12-03
... and so on
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5478

But I want it to be columns instead

```
2015-12-01  2015-12-02  2015-12-03  ...and so on
```

It seems that crosstab maybe should do the trick, but I only get errors:

```
select * from crosstab('(SELECT to_char(generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-01-05', interval '1 day'),'YYYY-MM-DD'))')
as ct (dynamic columns?)
```

How do I get crosstab to work with generate_series(date-date) and different intervals dynamically?

TIA

Comment: What about this `SELECT string_agg(col,',') from(
select to_char(generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-01-05', interval '1 day'),'YYYY-MM-DD') col
)t`

Comment: Yes, it is on the right track! But is there a way to get this into columns also?

Comment: How will you give column name for each items?, there will be 10 or even 100 columns can be produce

Comment: or this `select arcol[1],arcol[2],arcol[3],arcol[4],arcol[5] from (
SELECT array_agg(col) arcol from(
select to_char(generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-01-05', interval '1 day'),'YYYY-MM-DD') col
)t
)u
`

Comment: @wingedpanther "How will you give column name for each items?, there will be 10 or even 100 columns can be produce". Either just numbers or letter+number?

Comment: "or this select arcol[1],arcol[2],arcol[3],arcol[4],arcol[5]". Even better, but how do I do this dynamic without exact numbers of columns?

Comment: What is "arcol"? It seems to work on sqlfiddle but not in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking Reference from link [PostgreSQL query with generated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531728/postgresql-query-with-generated-columns/33547854#33547854).

you can generate columns dynamically:

```
create or replace function sp_test()
returns void as
$$

declare cases character varying;
declare sql_statement text;
begin
    drop table if exists temp_series;
    create temporary  table temp_series as
    SELECT to_char(generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-01-02', interval '1 day'),'YYYY-MM-DD') as series;

    select string_agg(concat('max(case when t1.series=','''',series,'''',' then t1.series else ''0000-00-00'' end) as ','"', series,'"'),',') into cases from temp_series;

    drop table if exists temp_data;
    sql_statement=concat('create temporary table temp_data as select ',cases ,' 
    from temp_series t1');

    raise notice '%',sql_statement;
    execute sql_statement;
end;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Call function in following  way to get output:

```
select sp_test(); select * from temp_data;
```

**Updated Function which takes two date paramaeters:**

```
create or replace function sp_test(start_date timestamp without time zone,end_date timestamp without time zone)
returns void as
$$

declare cases character varying;
declare sql_statement text;
begin
    drop table if exists temp_series;
    create temporary  table temp_series as
    SELECT to_char(generate_series(start_date,end_date, interval '1 day'),'YYYY-MM-DD') as series;

    select string_agg(concat('max(case when t1.series=','''',series,'''',' then t1.series else ''0000-00-00'' end) as ','"', series,'"'),',') into cases from temp_series;

    drop table if exists temp_data;
    sql_statement=concat('create temporary table temp_data as select ',cases ,' 
    from temp_series t1');

    raise notice '%',sql_statement;
    execute sql_statement;
end;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

**Function call:**

```
select sp_test('2015-01-01','2015-01-10'); select * from temp_data;
```

Comment: The function is created ok, but select sp_test() gives an error: relation "temp_series" does not exist Line 2: from temp_series t1

Comment: Please check it again. function may not be deleted or you may have ran old function because now i have created the `temp_series` temporary table , so same error will not come.

Comment: Correct - no errors. But I changed the interval to 2015-01-01-2015-01-05. It ended up in only 2 columns and 5 rows. It should be 5 columns with 1 row. One column for each date.

Comment: This may be  because you have changed in the function but not executed again , that's why it is still showing you same number of columns. I  am updating the function, which takes two parameters of dates in which you want the columns to be dynamically generated.

Comment: @sibert: check updated function in which you no need to change function always as I have added input params for start and end dates.

Comment: Still 2 columns and 5 rows each. With interval 5 dates. Not only 2.

Comment: Delete all functions you have created and then create function again which I posted last.

Comment: Weird. It looks OK in pgAdmin but fails in my frontend Omnis Studio. Same steps taken.

Comment: I am not familiar with functions. How do I send parameters to the function in order to make it dynamic. Like ***select sp_test(2015-01-01,2015-01-31)***?

Comment: you are calling it in wrong way. `select sp_test('2015-01-01','2015-01-31')`. you should use `single quotes(')` for parameter values.

Comment: Excellent! Works like expected. Thank you!